# Correct initialization of ReliableCollection from StateManager

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

Does anyone have any insights to which of the following two pseudo-patterns are the correct way of instantiating/utilizing reliable collections within a stateful service fabric service? Specifically, wondering if one approach is more performant, more memory-consuming or even more error prone.

Approach 1 (get instance from StateManager inside method):

```
public class MyService : IService {

  public async Task<string> GetSomeValueAsync(string input){
    var reliableDic = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>(StateKey);
    var result = await reliableDic.TryGetValue(input);
    return result.HasValue ? result.Value : null;
  }
}
```

Approach 2 (store collection as member variable on class)

```
public class MyService : IService {
  private bool _isInitialized;
  private readonly object _lock = new object();
  private IReliableDictionary<string, string> _dictionary;

  private async Task Initialize(){
     if (_isInitialized){
       return;
     }

     lock(_lock){
       if (_isInitialized){
         return;
       }

       _dictionary = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>(StateKey);
       _isInitialized = true;
     }
  }     

  public async Task<string> GetSomeValueAsync(string input){
    await Initialize();
    var result = await _dictionary.TryGetValue(input);
    return result.HasValue ? result.Value : null;
  }
}
```

So, approach 1 fetches the dictionary from the StateManager in each method while approach 2 does a lazy initialization check and then uses class members.

Most samples we see are using approach 1, but the idea behind approach 2 is to store the reliable dictionary in an instance field and avoid any `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync` hit in each method as well as centralize the handling of the `StateKey` which could be beneficial in larger services with many methods and potentially more reliable collections.

Would love to learn if there are any pitfalls or inefficiencies in either approach (obviously approach 2 is more verbose and uses more lines of code, but that is not the primary concern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is no real reason to cache result of `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync` except saving memory allocations of `Task` object or making it available in places where having `StateManager` available isn't appropriate.

The reason for this is quite simple - the `StateManager` already caches the instance of `IRealiableState` for you. So it returns the same instance each time you do `StateManager.GetOrAddAsync` ([here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9713) is the official answer from Microsoft).

You also can check it yourself with the very simple test (the `c` is `true`):

```
var q1 = stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>("MyDict")
                     .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var q2 = stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, string>>("MyDict")
                     .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var c = q1 == q2;
```